# Breaking out of .emacs script

Tags: emacs

I use two emacs (Aquamcs and text based emacs) on my Mac.
I normally use text based emacs for *just* editing something, so I don't want to load anything with it.

What I came up with is to have the checking code in .emacs to exit/break if it's text based emacs (darwin system but not aquamacs).

```
 (when (and (equal system-type 'darwin) (not (boundp 'aquamacs-version)))
     (exit) ??? (break) ????
 )
```

It seems to work, but I don't know how to break out of .emacs. How to do that?

### ADDED

I just wanted to speed up in loading text based emacs on my mac, and I thought about breaking out as a solution. Based on the helpful answers, I came up with the following code that runs .emacs only when it's not a text based emacs.

```
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)
(unless (null window-system)
```

Comment: The non-elisp solution always works; `alias emacs="/usr/bin/emacs -nw --no-init"`.  But really, why not just use `emacsclient -t` to connect to your running emacs from the terminal?

Comment: Very good! I think that is pretty much what Gareth Rees suggested, so if you find the time it would be nice if you marked his answer as correct.

Comment: I have the same question, but I don't find any command like break or exit of C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do exactly what you want. Some workarounds:

1. You can stop the evaluation of your `.emacs` by evaluating `(error "message")` but that's a bit unpleasant.
2. You can re-order your .emacs so that there's a `(unless (CONDITION) ...)` around the whole of the file.
3. You can run `emacs -Q FILE` when you're at the command line.

Why do you want to do this? Are you concerned at the time it takes to load your `.emacs`? If so, you might consider using the Emacs client/server instead.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how to exit as well but..... I would rather advice another kind of logic for your init file than a flat file with all different configurations.

Take for example your ~/.emacs (or better ~/.emacs.d/init.el) as your controller and files like ~/.emacs.d/aquamacs.el or ~/.emacs.d/textmode.el as your individual configuration files.

```
That would make your init having something like this :
(defun my-short-hostname() 
  (string-match "[0-9A-Za-z]+" system-name)
  (substring system-name (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
  )

;Load different config file in text mode or gui mode.
(if (null window-system)
    (load-file "~/.emacs.d/texmode-emacs.el")
  (load-file "~/.emacs.d/gui.el"))

;Load configuration for this host only, ie ~/.emacs.d/myhostname.el if exist
(if (file-exists-p 
     (downcase (concat "~/.emacs.d/" (my-short-hostname) ".el")))
    (load-file (downcase "~/.emacs.d/" (my-short-hostname) ".el"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having specific, different files to load conditionally from your `.emacs`, one for one setup, another for another setup.

Alternatively, just wrap the code for each setup in a `progn` and do the conditional in place, in `.emacs` itself.